# Accessing Value from stdClass

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help me with this.. 
I sum the value of two columns and subtract... but I can't convert the back to integer..

```
$query = $this->db->query("
     SELECT SUM(`Bought_Cost`) - SUM(`Sold_Cost`) 
     FROM `Stock_txn` 
     WHERE `Stock_Id` = '$stock_Id'
");
$bought_sold_cost = $query->result();
```

If I try `var_dump($bought_sold_cost)`;

I get :

```
Array( [0]=> stdClass Object( [SUM(`Bought_Cost`) - SUM(`Sold_Cost`) ] => 3000.00 ) )
```

I would like to use the array as a variable... any one with idea?

Comment: use `SELECT ... AS 'some_variable_name'...` then you can use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the column a name:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(Bought_Cost) - SUM(Sold_Cost) AS `difference` FROM Stock_txn WHERE Stock_Id = '$stock_Id'");
$bought_sold_cost = $query->result();
```

Then you will get:

```
Array( [0]=> stdClass Object( [difference] => 3000.00 ) )
```

Which can be accessed as `$bought_sold_cost[0]->difference`